# Binding to static methods in SharePoint Visual WebPart UserControls

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, sharepoint-2010, static, webforms

I am trying to bind the `Text` property of an `<asp:TextBox />` control to a static property on a static method.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text='<%# Test.Text("ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

from:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static string Text(string text)
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't appear to be working. If I set a breakpoint inside the method, it is never hit.

The following HTML is returned to the browser:

```
<input name="ctl00$m$g_007ce7d6_239f_413c_a8e9_8ed90deb20b1$ctl00$TextBox1" type="text" id="ctl00_m_g_007ce7d6_239f_413c_a8e9_8ed90deb20b1_ctl00_TextBox1">
```

However, when I call the method using the `<%=` markup, the markup is compiled correctly and the string is returned to the browser:

```
<%= this.Test.Text("ID") %>
```

I get no errors from the compiler.

Comment: What does it return to the browser? When you say, it is not working, it you get the text in the browser, what is not working?

Comment: @nunespascal I have updated the question to include the generated HTML for the `<asp:TextBox />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `<%# Test.Text("ID") %>.`

Refer the [Data-Binding expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This data will only be bound when you call DataBind, like this:

```
Page.DataBind();
```

A good place to call this is the Load event of the page.